# How can I return from and delete an object if a condition is not met

Tags: python, object, exit

I want a class which does not create the object if a specific condition is met

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, input):
        if input == condition:
          # get out of here and destroy this object to save memory
        self.var1 = input;
        # etc...
```

After the condition is met, the object is destroyed.

Comment: Why don't you check the condition before you create it?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest raising an Exception

```
class BadInitArgs(Exception):
    pass

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, input):
        if input != "expected":
          raise BadInitArgs
          # get out of here and destroy this object to save memor
        # etc...

a = MyClass("expected")
b = MyClass("unexpected")
```